# Multiple, Single Input File Form Fields

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script

**WHAT I'M TRYING TO DO**

When a "submit" button is clicked, I'm trying to run a function that will go over all `<input type="file">` fields and submit the files to Google Drive. 
I modified the original code [HERE](https://www.bettercloud.com/monitor/the-academy/allow-anyone-to-upload-files-directly-to-your-drive/). It works with a single file input field as expected.

**THE PROBLEM**

*see edits below 02/08/19*

I cannot get it to work for multiple `<input type="file">` fields. I tried to create a function that would determine if a given field was empty. If it was, skip it and move on to the next. What I have now is not working.

**OTHER**

The entire screen goes white when the button is pressed. Somehow, this works in the original form and my minor modifications, but not now and I don't understand why or how to fix it.

*Update: My current error in the console shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null.*

[image]

**WHAT I'VE TRIED**

See [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/nateomardavis/je80h6sk/7/) or below.

**`form.html`**

```
   <!doctype html>

<head>
  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      background-color: #FFFFFF;
    }

  </style>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <br>
  <br>
  <br>
  <div align="center">
    <p><img src="ENTER URL"></p>
    <table width="459" border="0">
      <tbody>
        <tr>
          <td width="462">
            <div align="center">
              <hr>
            </div>
            <form id="myForm" align="center">

              <label for="teamName">TEAM</label>
              <select name="teamName" id="teamName" name='teamName'></select>

              <label for="myName">YOUR NAME</label>
              <input type="text" name="myName" placeholder="Your name..">

              <label for="myFile">Passes</label>
              <input type="file" name="myFile" id="passes">
              <label for="myFile">Roster</label>
              <input type="file" name="myFile2" id="roster">
              <input type="submit" value="Upload File" id="clickMe" onclick="clickEvent();">
            </form>
            <div id="output"></div>


            <script>
              google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(buildTeamsList)
                .teams();


              function buildTeamsList(teamsArray) {
                var list = teamsArray;
                //var option = document.createElement('option');
                var option = '';

                for (var i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
                  option += '<option value="' + list[i] + '">' + list[i] + '</option>';
                }

                $('#teamName').append(option);
                //var select = document.getElementById('teamName');
                //select.appendChild(option);

              }

              function clickEvent() {

                var cE = document.getElementById("clickMe")
                cE.value = 'Uploading...';

                var fileCount1 = document.getElementById("passes").files.length
                console.log(fileCount1);
                var fileCount2 = document.getElementById("roster").files.length
                console.log(fileCount2);
                var x = document.getElementById("clickMe").parentNode;
                //document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =x;

                var y = document.getElementById("clickMe").parentNode;
                //document.getElementById("output").innerHTML =y;

                if (fileCount1 > 0) {
                  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles(x);
                  //.writeToSheet;

                } else if (fileCount2 > 0) {
                  google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded)
                    .uploadFiles2(y);

                } else {
                  return false;
                }


              };


              function fileUploaded(status) {
                document.getElementById('myForm').style.display = 'none';
                document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = status;
              }

            </script>
            <style>
              input {
                display: block;
                margin: 20px;
              }

            </style>
            <hr>
          </td>
        </tr>
      </tbody>
    </table>
    <h3>&nbsp;</h3>
    <p>&nbsp;</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

**`Code.gs`**

```
`function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');

}

function teams() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MYID');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('TEAMS');
  var range = sheet.getRange('A2:A1000');
  var values = range.getValues();

    var array1 = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {

    var column = values[i];
    var colA = column[0];


    if (colA != '') {

      array1.push(colA);
    }
  }

    var teamsArray = [];
  while (array1.length) teamsArray.push(array1.splice(0, 1));
  var lengthDivName2 = teamsArray.length;
  var widthDivName2 = teamsArray[0].length;



  Logger.log(teamsArray);
  return teamsArray;

}

function writeToSheet(form) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MYID');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('submissions');
  var range = sheet.getRange('A2');

  range.setValue(form.myName);

}

function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {

    var dropbox = "Check In Test";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile; 

    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);
    file.setName(form.teamName+ " - Passes");

    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }

}

function uploadFiles2(form) {

  try {

    var dropbox = "Check In Test";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile; 

    var file = folder.createFile(blob);    
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);
    file.setName(form.teamName + " - Roster");

    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl();

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }

}
```

**SIDE NOTES**

1. If anyone has a way I can create my list of `<select>` values
   (`function buildTeamsList(teamsArray)`) without JQuery, then great.
   You can see the lines above that I've commented out.
2. Obviously, I'm Frankenstein-ing this together and don't really
   understand how it all works; patience is appreciated.
3. I also tried what you see [HERE](https://jsfiddle.net/nateomardavis/25dbc74m/) for multiple files from a single field, but the problem there was I couldn't figure out how to rename the files in Code.gs whereas I could with this code. Because I ultimately want to write data to a spreadsheet, knowing how to do that (as I can with this code) is important.

**EDITS**

1. I changed the function to include parantheses as Tanaike suggested.
2. I did some more digging noticed, again at Tanaike's suggestion, that there were arguments to be passed to the function. Originally it was `(this.parentNode)`.
3. I tried that, but it still doesn't work.
4. I tried to select the `.parentNode` of the submit button (the form). My current error in the console shows `"Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null.`

Comment: Although I'm not sure about the arguments you want to give to the GAS functions, in your script, in order to run the GAS functions, please modify to ``google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles();`` and ``google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(fileUploaded).uploadFiles2();``. Please add ``()`` to both function names.

Comment: Ah I did miss that, and the arguments that were passed. Originally it was `uploadFiles(this.parentNode);` That is not working either. Again, no errors in the console. The screen just goes to white when the button is clicked. What argument should I be passing to make this work? I updated my question and fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nateomardavis/je80h6sk/5/

Comment: You should pass the form node. What does `this` refer to in your script?

Comment: I updated the question and my code. Basically, I tried to select the `.parentNode` of the submit button (the form). I've been getting this error: `Update: My current error in the console shows "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of null.`

Comment: Which line? Also why not just `document.getElementById('myForm')` ?

Comment: Since your last comment, I had gone back and tried that too. I still get the same error and the screen goes white.  I updated the question to show the log

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone that may come across this. I was able to make this work by changing the server-side (code.gs) function `uploadFiles(form)`. Now, one button and one function on the form collects from both file inputs.

https://jsfiddle.net/nateomardavis/kdpjo4s9/2/

```
function doGet(e) {
  return HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('form.html');

}

function teams() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MYID');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('TEAMS');
  var range = sheet.getRange('A2:A1000');
  var values = range.getValues();

  var array1 = [];

  for (var i = 0; i < values.length; ++i) {

    var column = values[i];
    var colA = column[0];


    if (colA != '') {

      array1.push(colA);
    }
  }

  var teamsArray = [];
  while (array1.length) teamsArray.push(array1.splice(0, 1));
  var lengthDivName2 = teamsArray.length;
  var widthDivName2 = teamsArray[0].length;



  Logger.log(teamsArray);
  return teamsArray;

}

function writeToSheet(form) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('MYID');
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName('submissions');
  var range = sheet.getRange('A2');

  range.setValue(form.myName);

}

function uploadFiles(form) {

  try {

    var dropbox = "Check In Test";
    var folder, folders = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(dropbox);

    if (folders.hasNext()) {
      folder = folders.next();
    } else {
      folder = DriveApp.createFolder(dropbox);
    }

    var blob = form.myFile;

    var file = folder.createFile(blob);
    file.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);
    file.setName(form.teamName + " - Passes");

    var blob2 = form.myFile2;

    var file2 = folder.createFile(blob2);
    file2.setDescription("Uploaded by " + form.myName);
    file2.setName(form.teamName + " - Roster");

    return "File uploaded successfully " + file.getUrl() + " and " + file2.getUrl();

  } catch (error) {

    return error.toString();
  }

}
```